# node.js: how to set global variable from within anonymous function?

Tags: node.js, variables, scope, global, anonymous

Global variables are considered bad practice, but I want to use them as a sort of simple "singleton" value.

The following contains three different ways of declaring variables in a global scope in NodeJS (I think). Function change2() succeeds in changing their values from "...one" to "...two". However function change3() does not succed in setting them to "...three".

How can I change the value of a global variable from inside an anonymous function? - I have also tried calling a setter method with no effect. The bind() invocation is just a helpless guess.

```
   global.v1 = 'v1: one';
   var v2 = 'v2: one';
   v3 = 'v3: one';

   function change2() {
        global.v1 = 'v1: two';
        v2 = 'v2: two';
        v3 = 'v3: two';
   };

   function change3() {
       (function() {
           global.v1 = 'v1: three';
           v2 = 'v2: three';
           v3 = 'v3: three';
       }).bind({v1:v1, v2:v2, v3:v3});
   };

   console.log (v1, v2, v3);
   change2();
   console.log (v1, v2, v3);
   change3();
   console.log (v1, v2, v3);
```

output is:

```
O:\node>node scope
v1: one v2: one v3: one
v1: two v2: two v3: two
v1: two v2: two v3: two

O:\node>
```

Comment: not a direct answer, but a file "v1.js" with contents `module.exports = {}` works even better for a simple singleton. then simple `require('./v1')` in your other modules.

Comment: In `change3()` you never actually execute the internal function.  `.bind()` just returns a new function, but you never actually call it.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 for spotting. Replacing `.bind(...)` with just `()` triggered the invocation and "...three" to be set.

Answer (score 1):

In `change3()` you never actually execute the internal function. `.bind()` just returns a new function, but you never actually call that new function.

If you want to call it, you'd have to add parens after the `.bind()`:

```
function change3() {
   (function() {
       global.v1 = 'v1: three';
       v2 = 'v2: three';
       v3 = 'v3: three';
   }).bind({v1:v1, v2:v2, v3:v3})();   // add parens at the end here
};
```

But, you don't even need the `.bind()` here as it isn't helping you.

```
function change3() {
   (function() {
       global.v1 = 'v1: three';
       v2 = 'v2: three';
       v3 = 'v3: three';
   })();   // add parens at the end here
};
```